# How to (where to) store info about real time actions in the website?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, web

I am developing a "Google Sheets" alike web app, and there has to be an ability for 2-50 people to edit the same table at the same time. So to avoid conflict when 2 people edit the same cell of the table, when person clicks on the cell, that cell has to become disabled(uneditable) to other people.

Question:

**How can I track what cell is disabled?**

1) Do I have to make mysql table that will be changing online dynamically(to store cell id which is being edited ) (I think this is super stupud idea)

2) Somehow make a variable that would be available for all the users at the same time(but I dont know how to do it)

Answer (score 0):

make a table with all the cells, and a field active with bloean. Then when some one clicks in a sell, you can set it to 0 by ajax. If its 0 you put a disable in the input.

I dont know how you doing this app, but i think you can do something like i said. Use ajax to send the info to the table in your DB.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about it (my first option), but is it correct in terms of performance? I mean, getting in/out of the DB everytime when someone clicks to the table?

Comment: Its the only way to do it. You cant "share" variables between users. Every time some one clicks on a cell you have to check if it is active or not, if it is, you block it, if its not you allow the user to edit it, but at same time you have to block it in the DB so others users cant edit it

Answer (score 0):

The only way to persist some data across several users is to have some storage on back end. There are a lot of options (not only MySQL): you can use mongo, firebase or even store this information in text file (not recommended), but you need to store it somehow to let others know about situation with your table.